# How to properly handle cross contract call errors

Tags: ink, smart-contract, cross-contract-call

In the scenario where a cross-contract call from contract A to contract B fails, how can we manage the resulting errors? Specifically, if the call from A to B is unsuccessful, what are the options for updating the storage of contract A based on this outcome?

Comment: I'm gonna try and write a better answer soon, but you should take a look at the "try" methods from the CallBuilder: https://docs.rs/ink_env/4.0.1/ink_env/call/struct.CallBuilder.html#method.try_invoke-2.

Basically there are three types of errors to handle: Environment errors, Language errors, and Contract errors. Storage changes aren't as big a hassle as in Substrate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*All the code I mention here is available [in this repo](https://github.com/HCastano/cross-contract-errors).*

There are three types of errors that you need to may want to handle when doing
cross-contract calls

1. Contract Errors: defined by the smart contract you're interacting with
2. Language Errors ([`ink::LangError`](https://docs.rs/ink/latest/ink/enum.LangError.html)): defined by the programming language you're using, e.g ink!
3. Environment Errors ([`ink::env::Error`](https://docs.rs/ink_env/4.1.0/ink_env/enum.Error.html)): defined by the underlying execution environment, e.g `pallet-contracts`

In all cases we can handle these different errors using [`CallBuilder::try_invoke`](https://docs.rs/ink_env/4.1.0/ink_env/call/struct.CallBuilder.html#method.try_invoke) and
continue execution (including writing to storage) if we wish.

First, let's assume the contract we're calling into (i.e callee) has the two following message:

```rust
#[ink(message)]
pub fn contract_error(&mut self) -> Result<(), ()> {
    Err(())
}
                                                     
#[ink(message)]
pub fn environment_error(&mut self) {
    panic!("ContractTrapped")
}
```

Next, in our caller contract has the following type definitions in place (it'll make things a bit easier to follow).

```rust
use ink::MessageResult;
use ink::env::Result as EnvResult;

type ContractResult = core::result::Result<(), ()>;
```

We can handle the different errors as follows:

**Contract Error**

```rust
#[ink(message)]
pub fn contract_error(&mut self, address: AccountId) {
    let result = build_call::<DefaultEnvironment>()
        .call(address)
        .exec_input(ExecutionInput::new(Selector::new(ink::selector_bytes!(
            "contract_error"
        ))))
        .returns::<Result<(), ()>>()
        .try_invoke();
                                                                            
    match result {
        EnvResult::Ok(MessageResult::Ok(ContractResult::Err(_))) => {
            self.value = !self.value;
        }
        _ => unimplemented!(),
    }
}
```

**Language Error**

```rust
#[ink(message)]
pub fn lang_error(&mut self, address: AccountId) {
    let result = build_call::<DefaultEnvironment>()
        .call(address)
        .exec_input(ExecutionInput::new(Selector::new(ink::selector_bytes!(
            "not_a_real_selector"
        ))))
        .returns::<()>()
        .try_invoke();
                                                                            
    // Note: You can match on more specific `LangError`s here.
    //
    // See [`ink::LangError`] for more.
    match result {
        EnvResult::Ok(MessageResult::Err(_)) => {
            self.value = !self.value;
        }
        _ => unimplemented!(),
    }
}
```

**Environment Error**

```rust
#[ink(message)]
pub fn environment_error(&mut self, address: AccountId) {
    let result = build_call::<DefaultEnvironment>()
        .call(address)
        .exec_input(ExecutionInput::new(Selector::new(ink::selector_bytes!(
            "environment_error"
        ))))
        .returns::<()>()
        .try_invoke();
                                                                            
    // Note: You can match on more specific `EnvError`s here.
    //
    // See [`ink::env::Error`] for more.
    match result {
        EnvResult::Err(_) => {
            self.value = !self.value;
        }
        _ => unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

Comment: amazing Hernando thanks for sharing! thanks to your help i also benefited from your response in this example that builds upon the basic-contract-caller example https://github.com/ltfschoen/InkTemplate/pull/16/commits/3433a89ff76fb8d0c884aa41bc17a2c5a1faad39

although i couldn't find any documentation about `EnvError` in the docs https://docs.rs/ink/latest/ink/?search=EnvError, but i found the different error codes in the ink! codebase