# Why is this cross-contract call misbehaving?

Tags: error, astar, cross-contract-call

```rust
#[ink(message)]
        pub fn create_new_better_payment(
            &mut self,
            _value: Balance,
            _arbiter_provider: AccountId,
            _deadline: u64,
            //this deadline is deadline that will be added to current time once the audit is assigned to an auditor.
        ) -> Result<()> {
            let _now = self.env().block_timestamp();
            let x = PaymentInfo {
                value: _value,
                starttime: _now,
                auditor: self.env().caller(),
                arbiterprovider: _arbiter_provider,
                patron: self.env().caller(),
                deadline: _deadline,
                currentstatus: AuditStatus::AuditCreated,
            };
            assert_ne!(_value, 0);
            let xyz = ink::env::call::build_call::<Environment>()
                .call(self.stablecoin_address)
                .gas_limit(0)
                .exec_input(
                    ink::env::call::ExecutionInput::new(ink::env::call::Selector::new(
                        ink::selector_bytes!("transfer_from"),
                    ))
                    .push_arg(self.env().caller())
                    .push_arg(self.env().account_id())
                    .push_arg(_value),
                )
                .returns::<bool>()
                .invoke();
            if xyz {
                self.env().emit_event(TokenIncoming {
                    id: self.current_audit_id,
                });
                self.audit_id_to_payment_info
                    .insert(&self.current_audit_id, &x);
                self.env().emit_event(AuditInfoUpdated {
                    id: Some(self.current_audit_id),
                    payment_info: Some(x),
                    updated_by: Some(self.env().caller()),
                });
                self.current_audit_id = self.current_audit_id + 1;
                return Ok(());
            } else {
                return Err(Error::InsufficientBalance);
            }
        }
```

Why is this function misbehaving?

I am trying to send the caller's `ERC20` tokens to this contract in the above function, The rest of everything is working, but not the cross-contract calling.

What am I doing wrong here?
This function will update the state of its contract but won't transfer the `ERC20` tokens of other contract.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `approve` before `transfer_from`. Most likely ERC20 contract returned an error. You need to handle errors from the cross contract call.

See more about error handling [here](https://github.com/swankyhub/rmrk-lazy-mint/blob/507552ced20d948b6acb34eb75855f84f30357fa/rmrk_proxy/proxy.rs#L126)
and [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7634/how-to-properly-handle-cross-contract-call-errors/7843#7843)

Comment: I've done the approve part, it is not working.

Comment: Than implement an error handling to see an error from ERC20 contract.

Comment: if there were an error on the called contract, wouldn't the whole function fail?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I had the same issue with [this](https://github.com/swankyhub/rmrk-lazy-mint/blob/507552ced20d948b6acb34eb75855f84f30357fa/rmrk_proxy/proxy.rs#L126) contract. Cross contract call didn't fail, but token was not minted because of bad value passed to the call

Comment: Can you suggest the exact changes? I tried [this](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7634/how-to-properly-handle-cross-contract-call-errors/7843#7843) solution but I still can't seem to make it work.

Comment: if you don't handle error of the called contract as an error of the original call - it won't fail automatically. Call `?` or panic! and see the error.